# sqlalchemy insert blob raises UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, zlib

Trying to reuse a working Python code from Mac to Windows. The code compresses a utf8 string using gzip and inserts the output as a blob using SQLAlchemy.

However I get the following error after the insertion:

```
        UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 15: character maps to <undefined>
```

The relevant section:

```
        from sqlalchemy import *
        import zlib

        pcaxis_table = Table('pcaxis_data', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)

        try:
            response = urllib2.urlretrieve(url_source)
        except Exception as e:
            print url_source
            raise e

        infile = response.read()
        px_file = infile.decode('cp1252').encode('utf-8')

        cmpstr = zlib.compress(px_file)


        #out = StringIO.StringIO()
        #with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=out, mode="w") as f:
        #    f.write(px_file)

        ins = pcaxis_table.insert(values = {'TableSQL':tableSQL,
                                            'zip_file':cmpstr, #out.getvalue()
                                            })
        ins.execute()
```

Trace... (it fails when trying to decode the blob as cp1252)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\base.py", line 386, in execute
    return e._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1758, in _execute_clauseelement
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(elem, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 826, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 958, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1162, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 951, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 436, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 100, in execute
    query = query % escaped_args
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 15, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 6: character maps to <undefined>
```

and the MySQL table:

```
create table pcaxis_data(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    TableSQL varchar(25),
    zip_file BLOB,
    inserttime TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Can you post the table definition?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `.decode('cp1252')`. Windows-1252 codepage doesn't use all bytes (so for example byte `8f` is not used and fails to decode). You can use `latin1` instead.

Is `response` actually a Windows-1252 text? If it is not, decoding it as such makes no sense.

`zlib.compress` takes a bytestring parameter and `response` is a bytestring, you can compress it directly, without re-encoding.

Comment: thanks for the response. I have tried several possible decodings (latin 1, cp1252, utf8, ascii), all combinations ended in raising the same error at converting the 0x8f byte, and again the same code works on Mac. I tried using a latin 1 and a utf8 sql db, does not seem to matter.

Comment: Can you post the whole stack trace so we can see *where* the exception actually takes place? And can you also provide justification for the whole `.decode().encode()` combo?

Comment: I edit the post with the trace, it appears when trying to insert the blob. It seems it tries to parse the blob to a unicode string and assumes the wrong encoding of the binary data. I am using the last version of sqlalchemy. I encode the string to utf8 to make subsequent calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the issue. How? Upgrading pymysql from circa 0.6.0 to 0.6.3. 
What was the problem? The pymysql driver tries to escape the binary data by doing a conversion to unicode. The byte \x08 does not map to unicode using UTF8 nor Latin1. Thats why this failed.